# Невозможно прочитать length of undefined

Tags: javascript

Кто-то может подсказать почему в данном сегменте кода интерпретатор выдает следующую ошибку — Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?

```
function getGuess() {
    prompt("Type in some character");
}

var guess = getGuess();
if (guess === null) {
    break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert("Please enter a single letter.");
}
```

Comment: скрыть ошибку отсутствия return можно было бы нестрогой проверкой `guess == null` вместо `guess === null`, но тогда всегда был бы заход в условие и вызов `break;`

Comment: Вам не понятно почему нельзя прочитать длину неустановленной переменной, или почему не срабатывает условие if, или почему переменной ничего не присваивается?

Comment: Но ведь prompt по идее должен и так возвращать значение. Зачем тут return?

Comment: Переменная установлена. Мне не понятно, почему не удается прочитать длину установленной переменной.

Comment: @AlexStelmakh, потому что prompt вернул значение в пустоту. А функция _getGuess_ - ничего не возвращает, поэтому `getGuess()` всегда будет _undefined_. Так как в функции нет ни одного `return`

Comment: `function getGuess() {
    return prompt("Type in some character");
}`

Comment: Но ведь prompt по идее должен и так возвращать значение. Зачем тут return?
Добавил return. Ошибки нет. Но все же, я думал, что return  возвращает значение по умолчанию. Или это не так?

Comment: @AlexStelmakh, prompt это обычная функция, которая возвращает значение. ты ее вызвал. получил значение и вернул его из функции. Далее в месте вызова ты никуда не сохранил возвращенное значение, и вышел из функции _getGuess_ ничего не вернув

Comment: _я думал, что return возвращает значение по умолчанию_ - не понял этого предположения

Comment: Пройди по ссылке на вопрос-дубликат, там та же самая проблема

Comment: Как никуда не сохранил? —

Comment: var guess = getGuess();

Comment: примите как данность - если в функции нет `return`, то возвращенное значение - `undefined`. Такой язык. В других - может быть иначе.

Comment: @AlexStelmakh, `var guess = getGuess();` здесь сохраняется результат функции `getGuess`. А теперь покажи где ты сохраняешь результат функции prompt?

Comment: @Grundy как мне казалось результат вызова prompt принадлежит функции getGuess(). Но теперь я совсем запутался. Получается без return prompt возвращается в никуда?

Comment: @AlexStelmakh, именно об этом и были предыдущие комментарии. _результат вызова prompt принадлежит функции getGuess_ - что значит принадлежит?

Comment: Прошу прощения за возможно глупые вопросы, но как учиться по другому? У кого еще спрашивать как не здесь? Я иногда готов на стену лезть, когда вроде все понятно, пишешь и нихрена не работает. Это так мысли вслух.

Comment: Если без лишних слов, получается return must have?

Comment: если функция _должна_ вернуть значение у нее _должен_ быть `return`. Исключение составляют [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) но это отдельная история